# Prevent Git push from overwriting a directory

Tags: git, heroku

Quick one.

I'm writing an app and I regularly push versions to Heroku using git.

Users are able to upload images to the app. When I push a version from local the folder where those images are stored is overwritten by the blank folder on my local app.

How can I prevent this and/or are there any alternative methods to maintaining consistency here.

I tried a .gitignore file but it doesn't seem to work:

```
static/media/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that `git push` is overwriting anything. It's that [Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): any changes you make to it are lost every time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day), as well as when you deploy a new version and in a few other situations.

Heroku [recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) using something like Amazon S3 for storing user uploads. Files uploaded to a third-party service like this will survive dyno restarts. They'll also be available to multiple dynos, e.g. if you ever need to scale your application.